# Why does Stack Overflow allow to post non English content?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, english

Usually non English content will be flagged as *unclear what you're asking.* or *very low quality*. If so, why is it allowed to post non English characters when writing a question?

If Stack Overflow were to validate the text input, there is no need to flag and no reason to see a non English question for other users.

[image]

This thought came to mind after seeing this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57264172/t%c3%b4i-c%c3%b3-m%e1%bb%99t-h%c3%a0m-post-g%e1%bb%adi-gmail-cho-kh%c3%a1ch-h%c3%a0ng-nh%c6%b0ng-l%e1%ba%a1i-g%e1%bb%adi-cho-ch%c3%adnh-t%c3%b4i)

Comment: Not related, but that *"Non English Character"* bothers me... technically speaking there is no English alphabet, the name of it is **Roman** alphabet. The world is so comfortable and convenient for native English speakers that most of them don't even care about that (yes, this is a rant, it will be soon deleted by a mod).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, isn't it named latin alphabet?

Comment: @Vega it's the same thing, Roman or Latin alphabet: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_alphabet

Comment: @GerardoFurtado what does that whole message even mean? If something *is allowed* why is it an error?

Comment: I think we all recognize the hand of a developer in formulating that error message. It needs someone with technical writing skills to transform that message into something that is fit for purpose and audience. None of the error messages I put in my software over the last year are still in production today. They all had to be re-written.

Comment: The community is excellently equipped to downvote these post into oblivion. Once it gathers three downvotes it will be removed from the frontpage, killing off most traffic to a question. And it would also quickly gather close votes, and perhaps a custom flag, making it closed in no-time. There is just no need for this feature IMO.

Comment: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57262435) hanged open for 7 hours and even has got an accepted answer. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57226017) pollutes the site for about 4 days now (probably waiting for some kind soul to answer it in comments). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/23605228) isn't even closed after 7 days because review timed out. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57170675) hangs on the site for about a week. <--- Your expectations sound a bit too optimistic, sorry @Luuklag

Comment: @gnat you can always find exceptions. Doesn't change the fact that the community can close these questions quickly. That there currently aren't enough reviewers, apparently, is a separate issue. That a question asked during the middle of the European night / late US evening doesn't get closed quickly shouldn't be a surprise.

Comment: @Luuklag sad thing is, 4 above examples are 2/3 of non-English posts I stumbled upon in a week (there could be one more but I asked SOCVR folks to take care of it so it was quickly deleted). That is, my personal experience suggests that community cleanup is not quite efficient. (I [asked at SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/46900850#46900850) if they can help with this stuff)

Comment: @gnat I constructed [this search query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=Votes&q=is%3aq%20closed%3ano%20created%3a7d%20score%3a...0%20-How%20-What%20-have%20-want%20-try) (that I think is most likely to find posts not in English) And I only found 2 posts that weren't in English. On both I piled the 4th close vote.

Answer (score 24):

If I'm asking a question about rendering Shift-JIS characters, it would be ***immensely*** inconvenient to be presented with some dialog that tells me I can't post my question.

Comment: How about allowing in code format only ?

Comment: So then we'd have the same problem - people asking questions not in English but instead, they're now wrapped in code blocks.  We've solved nothing.

Comment: How about if non English content is can't post to SO immediately ! If any other character have include , go to review queue first ....

Comment: @hs-dev2MR then what about posting an error message? Is that also supposed to be posted in code format, even if it's not code? Or what if somebody comes in and writes something in German or Swedish? They are using "English characters" but not actually the English language, yet your suggestion does nothing to address that. As a side note, I tried entering random cyrillic characters in a question to see what happens and I got a message in Russian directing me to the Russian language version of SO but didn't stop me from posting. This seems way better - a soft stop with just a warning.

Comment: @VLAZ You are right ! I got it , the discussion is over for me :> Thank all your response ..

Comment: It's still possible (necessary?) to filter out posts that don't have any english characters in the body.